# Python: flood filling of multidimensional image

Tags: python, image-processing, flood-fill

I have a binary multidimensional image. And I want to get some implementation of flood fill that will give me the next:

1. List of connected regions (with adjacent pixels with value `True`).
2. For each region I want to get its bounding box and list of pixel coordinates of all pixels from the interconnected region.

Is something like that implemented?

Comment: What's a binary multidimensional image?

Comment: A multidimensional `numpy.ndarray` with boolean values.

Comment: for 1 you could start with "where((im[:,1:] & im[:,:-1]) | (im[1:,:] & im[:-1,:]))" kind of thing, obviously modified to the number of dimensions

Comment: For the 2D image case, you would simply perform a Depth-First-Search with the starting location and find all pixels that form part of the connected components defined by that region... however, if you're going into multi-dimensional, you could have a region that spans over all of the slices and so you could quickly run out of memory here.... Are we talking about having like a 3D volume where each `True` pixel means that this belongs to a 3D object?

Comment: @Felix - Here's a MATLAB implementation - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12184-floodfill3d/content//FloodFill3D.m - Even though it's not Python `numpy`, a lot of the syntax between the two are quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell yeah! `scipy.ndimage.measurements` module helps!